# When exactly are translations deployed?

Tags: support, localization, russian-stackoverflow, international-sites, deployment

Related: [Нет перевода текста на заблокированных вопросах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9374/15479).

We have added new translation (https://ru.traducir.win/string/12746).

> [image: Traducir]

But after the new revision deployment (rev 2019.7.29.34466) this translation was not released.

Previously SE employee told us, that translation are released during new revision deployment.

Could you clarify this? When exactly are translations deployed? Are those separate processes?

Comment: Did you use traducir? did the translation were aproved and pushed to transifex? did some CM on SE did a pull to get the new translation?

Comment: @gbianchi yes, it was approved. Nicolas told us, that currently translations should be deployed with site engine deployments. There is no need to do any manual actions for that.

Comment: Yes, but firsts traducir should upload them to transifex, and after that a CM has to do a pull of them to codebase.. probably that didn't happen yet?

Comment: @gbianchi hm, we have added translation on Saturday. AFAIK, transifex has this string translated (`4013c81d86353e2d424386b06324a83b`). So, we should wait Nicolas to press the button, right?